# Entity Framework View usage issue

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view, edmx

I have a view on 4 tables which is loaded into my EDMX file.

For the query

```
select * from vwData where column1=@col1  (works fine)
```

But when we use EF to pull data like below

```
entities.vwData.Where(x => x.column1 == @col1) (this timeout)
```

When we did the trace it shows EF has created as:

```
(@p__linq__0 int)
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1],
    [Extent1].[Column2] AS [Column2],
FROM 
    (SELECT [vwData].[Column1]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    (CAST( [Extent1].[Column1] AS int) = @p__linq__0)
```

If we closely examine the above SQL, first the view executes and then `where` is applied which timeouts because of large data. Is there anyway to make the view work along with `where` condition?

Comment: Why is it CASTing? Does your model not match the schema?

Comment: I am not sure why Extent1 is getting created even the schema correctly matches.